# Tengo un archivo ejecutable pero determinados botones no funcionan

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Mi problema es que tengo un archivo ejecutable del programa que desarrollé. Pero al entrar a una pantalla un botón que es usado para llamar a un calendario no funciona. Yo use para hacer el ejecutable pyinstaller, y estuve leyendo post de aquí,  y documentación que no acepta librerias originarias de Python asi que por lo que entiendo puede estar ahí el tema. Quisiera saber si me ayudan donde puedo leer como hacer esta configuraciones para que acepta los modulos que use. Muchas gracias.
PD: No creo necesario mostrar el código ya que en el script corre todo correctamente.

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: El error era "Pero al entrar a una pantalla un botón que es usado para llamar a un calendario no funciona." pero ya lo resolvi!